# Validate only one checkbox selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have two checkboxes and I want to avoid recording the form without selecting one of them, code is as follows;

```
If CheckBox1.Value <> True Then
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "You should select one option"
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This code only retrieves the first checkbox result, but I want to retrieve the second one as well, please provide your advice on this, thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:-

```
If Not (CheckBox1.Value Or CheckBox2.Value) Then
    MsgBox "You should select one option"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Option:

```
Select Case True
    Case CheckBox1.Value, CheckBox2.Value
    Case Else: Msgbox "Check At Least One Option"
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
If CheckBox1.Value <> True or CheckBox2.Value <> True Then
    MsgBox "You should select one option"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

If CheckBox1.Value <> True And CheckBox2.Value <> True Then
        MsgBox "You should select one option"
   Else
        Exit Sub
   End If

Comment: This has already been covered, nearly word for word, in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54994300/2605758).

Comment: Given that @michael is a new user, I suspect he was busy trying to answer the question and did not the page refresh with the exact same answer already published.